# Special leniency conditions for a U.S. female spouse residing abroad with children or pregnant to bring her foreign male spouse into the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, marriage

Are there any leniency conditions for a U.S. female spouse(U.S. citizen) under the following condition to bring her foreign male spouse into the U.S.?

Conditions

1. Currently residing in the foreign country
2. Does not have a job in the U.S. or anywhere else.
3. Either pregnant or has a child/children.

So basically she is in a condition where having a job is nearly impossible due to either pregnancy or children.

As far as I could search for, the U.S. citizen has to either

1. prove 125% of the poverty line income(depends on the State?)
   or
2. prove 5 times of the 125% of the poverty line income in cash or real estate value.

How would a pregnant woman or a mum bring her husband into the U.S. ?

Comment: Do you have a source for the 125% requirement? The only source I found said 100%.  Also, in the US, pregnancy is generally considered to prevent a woman from working for only a few weeks, as unreasonable as this may seem.  How was she supporting herself before she became pregnant?

Comment: I can imagine a situation where the couple is living abroad together and either both of them are making money in that country(not U.S.) or her husband is supporting her as she is either pregnant or has an infant to look after.